# I am trying to draft a smart contract, the remix IDE auto complete is not working. Anyone experienced the same in the past?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

I am trying to draft a smart contract, the remix auto complete is not working. I tried both windows and Mac. All browsers like Chrome, Edge, Brave, Safari.. no luck...

I tried enabling clipboard permission, copying code from other IDE etc. as per some other threads.

Any help will be largely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try asking your question over here

https://gitter.im/ethereum/remix